# Why are Title and Comment field for a contact always null?

Tags: tapkey

When I try to use Put or Patch for a contact object, the comment and title field always remain 'null'.

For instance, this is the json I use to perform a PUT:

{
"IpId" : "tapkey",
"Identifier" : "emailaddress here",
"Title" : "Test title",
"Comment" : "Test comment"
}

This executes with 200 OK. The contact that I immediately get return has the comment and title field set to 'null'. The contact is successfully created though.

For a PATCH the same thing happens.

Regards,

Stan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I used a POST method to execute the PUT. Because the contact was created and a HTTP 200 was returned, I never saw this error.

So the behavior for sending a PUT body to the contacts URL using the POST method will result in:

- HTTP 200
- Creation of the contact, but without title and comment
- Result is an array with 1 contact, the new one

Using the PUT method of course solved all my problems

Thanks anyway

Stan

Answer (score 0):

Field's names must start with lowercase letter.

For PUT request it actually works both ways. You can define it with e.g. `Title` or `title` and it will be accepted.

For PATCH request you are completely right, this only accepts lowercase letters. After changing this, it works as expected.

```
{
  "title": "my title",
  "comment": "my comment"
}
```

We will update our documentation to reflect this on PUT endpoint.

Comment: For me it still does not work. This is what I send 
{
 "ipId": "tapkey",
 "identifier": "email",
 "title": "test title",
 "comment": "test comment"
}

This is what I get returned:
[{
 "id": "newcontactid",
 "clientRef": null,
 "ownerId": "ownerid",
 "comment": null,
 "ipId": "tapkey",
 "ipUserId": null,
 "identifier": "email",
 "email": "email",
 "ipUserName": "email",
 "isActive": true,
 "title": null
}]

Comment: Can you provide some more details on which endpoint and request method are you using? It is unexpected that you get a list of contacts as a result.